Можно ли подключить туннель с обфускацией WireGuard в мобильной версии?
На виртуальный сервер поставил WireGuard с обфускацией. При попытке подключить туннель в мобильной версии появляется ошибка: >Невозможно импортировать туннель: неизвестный атрибут в interface

Проблема была в отсутствии поддержки обфускации на официальной программы от Wireguard. Если используете Wireguard Obfuscation, то для подключения к туннелю используйте другое по (например amneziaVPN)
